# Extract an image (jpg) from a math plot lib window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've struck out trying to find a way to make a copy of contents of the window from matplotlib directly into memory - i would like to avoid saving it into an intermediate PNG file just to read it back into memory as below. 
Any recommendations? thanks.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# draw into window with detected objects bounding boxes
ax = utils.viz.plot_bbox(img, bbox, scores=scores, labels=labels,
                                 thresh=ARGS.thresh, class_names=CLASSNAMES,
                                 absolute_coordinates=False)
plt.show(block=False)
# capture contents of window to disk
plt.savefig ('out.png')  
# read from disk for use down stream
img2 = cv2.imread('out.png')
# use img2 down stream
```

thanks

Comment: Use an in-memory file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fig.canvas.tostring_rgb`.
Here's some sample code, details in the comments.

```
# create a dummy image to plot
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(20,20,3))

# you need a figure to use canvas methods
# if you didn't create yours you can probably get it with plt.gcf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot your stuff
ax.imshow(img)
# force draw
fig.canvas.draw()
# save buffer
w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
buffer = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(h, w, 3)

# display your plot
plt.show()

# look at the buffer
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(buffer)
plt.show()
```

First plot

[image: figure 1]

Exported buffer

[image: buffer]